# Jquery onclick doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

While I'm certain that the answer must be incredibly simple and obvious, I can't for the life of me figure it out. Please forgive this newbie.

I have the following code in a js file:

```
$("#news-updates").onclick = function () {
    $("#news-content").toggle();
    $("#instruction").toggle();
}
```

The purpose of the code is to hide one object (instruction) and show another (news-content), then to do the opposite the next time it's clicked. Here's the HTML:

```
<section class = "news-updates" id = "news-updates">
    <h2>News & Updates</h2>
    <p id = "instruction">Tap here to open</p>
    <div id = "news-content">Lorem ipsum</div>
</section>
```

And in case it's somehow relevant, the CSS:

```
#news-updates {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ECECEC;
    float: right;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    #instruction {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    #news-content {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

When I click the section, nothing happens. The mouse doesn't even change. Please, how do I make this work?

Comment: where is instruction?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to update the rest of the question when I changed it... It wasn't the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#news-updates").click(function () {
        $("#news-content").toggle();
        $("#instruction").toggle();
    })
});
```

Direct assigning, as you did, is for pure javascript, while you are using jQuery. Also function should be assigned when DOM is loaded, so I am adding onload method.

Answer (score 0):

Correct instance for use jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#news-updates").click(function () {
     $("#news-content").toggle();
     $("#instruction").toggle();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is not a jquery function. You are adding a new function called `onclick` to the jQuery object.  You should be doing something like this:

```
$("#news-updates").on('click', function () {
  $("#news-content").toggle();
  $("#instruction").toggle();
});
```